# Qt - Cannot run PX4 .launch file

Tags: ros, px4, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently adopted the ROS plugin for Qt Creator for its use in profiling ROS nodes. However, it seems like the build/run settings cannot be set up to launch anything related to PX4. Is it possible? An example is when I set the Run tab up to roslaunch local_planner local_planner_stereo.launch that are part of the PX4 object avoidance. It builds fine but then fails on `Resource not found: px4`
I can run

```
. ~/Firmware/Tools/setup_gazebo.bash ~/Firmware ~/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:~/Firmware
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}:~/catkin_ws/src/avoidance/sim/models
```

In the terminal window that popped up, then launch it successfully, but by then I have lost the profiling attachments. I'd be happy to provide any further details if asked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351970/qt---cannot-run-px4-.launch-file/) by [magnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/54538/magnus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a solution. Since the ROS plugin for Qt creator sources the `/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, some of those environment variables from that process seem to override the ones that point to PX4. However by appending the above snippet to to the `/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` file, it now correctly assigns the environment variables.

This is the resulting setup.bash file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in

CATKIN_SHELL=bash

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"

. ~/Firmware/Tools/setup_gazebo.bash ~/Firmware ~/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:~/Firmware
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}:~/catkin_ws/src/avoidance/avoidance/sim/models
```

---

Originally posted by [magnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/54538/magnus/) with karma: 33 on 2020-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1